# Displaying only one frame at a time in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been struggling with this for a while. I think I'm missing some simple piece of information and I hope you guys can help clear this up for me.

I'm trying to get tkinter to display different frames which I will eventually place widgets inside of. Here's what I did:

1. I've made a class that is supposed to initialize the window and make all the different frames the program will run.
2. I've made a separate class for each frame(I'm intending to have variables associated with the different classes when the program is done), and assigned a variable that will start that class up and make it run it's **init** function
3. I ended the StartUp class by telling it to tkraise() the frame I want displayed, and that's where things stop working correctly.

I set each frame to a different color, so when you run this program you will see that they split the screen space up instead of one being raised to the top. What am I missing?

One last point, I am purposely trying to spell everything out in my program, I learn better that way. I left it so I have to type tkinter.blah-blah-blah in front of each tkinter command so I can recognize them easily, and I decided not to have my classes inherit Frame or Tk or anything. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing.

```
import tkinter

class StartUp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x300')

        self.container = tkinter.Frame(master=self.root, bg='blue')
        self.container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        self.page1 = Page1(self)
        self.page2 = Page2(self)

        self.page1.main_frame.tkraise()


class Page1():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.main_frame = tkinter.Frame(master=parent.container, bg='green')
        self.main_frame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)


class Page2():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.main_frame = tkinter.Frame(master=parent.container, bg='yellow')
        self.main_frame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)


boot_up = StartUp()
boot_up.root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `pack(side='top', ...)`, `top` doesn't refer to the top of the containing widget, it refers to the top of any empty space in the containing widget. `Page` initially takes up all of the space, and then when you pack `Page2`, it goes *below* `Page1` rather than being layered on top of it.

If you are using the strategy of raising one window above another, you need to either use `grid` or `place` to layer the widgets on top of each other. The layering is something `pack` simply can't do.

Your other choice is to call `pack_forget` on the current window before calling `pack` on the new windowl